# Matlab not accepting whole number as index

Tags: matlab, indexing, precision

I am using a while loop with an index t starting from 1 and increasing with each loop.
I'm having problems with this index in the following bit of code within the loop:

```
dt = 100000^(-1);
t = 1;
equi = false;
while equi==false

 ***some code that populates the arrays S(t) and I(t)*** 

t=t+1;   
if (t>2/dt)
        n = [S(t) I(t)];
        np = [S(t-1/dt) I(t-1/dt)];
        if sum((n-np).^2)<1e-5
            equi=true;
        end
end
```

First, the code in the "if" statement is accessed at `t==200000` instead of at `t==200001`.

Second, the expression `S(t-1/dt)` results in the error message `"Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals"`, even though `(t-1/dt)` is whole and equals  `1.0000e+005` . 
I guess I can solve this using "round", but this worked before and suddenly doesn't work and I'd like to figure out why. 
Thanks!

Comment: Firstly, `dt=1e-5` is a nicer (IMO) way of writing `100000^(-1)`. Secondly, what does replacing `1/dt` by `1e5` do? If that helps, it might prove more useful to write `r=1e5` and then `dt=1/r` when you need `dt`.

Answer (score 3):

> the expression S(t-1/dt) results in the error message "Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals", even though (t-1/dt) is whole and equals 1.0000e+005

Is it really? ;)

```
mod(200000 - 1/dt, 1)
%ans = 1.455191522836685e-11
```

Your index is not an integer. This is one of the things to be aware of when working with floating point arithmetic. I suggest reading this excellent resource: ["What every computer scientist should know about floating-point Arithmetic"](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf).

You can either use `round` as you did, or store `1/dt` as a separate variable (many options exist).

Comment: Thanks, Jatin and Lorem Ipsum. I realized that I ran into some inaccuracies (and therefore used the `round` fix). I just wonder how come it worked for hundreds of times over the last months as it was, and only now the problem arises.

Answer (score 0):

Matlab is lying to you.  You're running into floating point inaccuracies and Matlab does not have an honest printing policy.  Try printing the numbers with full precision:

```
dt = 100000^(-1);
t = 200000;
fprintf('2/dt == %.12f\n',2/dt) % 199999.999999999971
fprintf('t - 1/dt == %.12f\n',t - 1/dt) % 100000.000000000015
```

While powers of 10 are very nice for us to type and read, `1e-5` (your `dt`) cannot be represented exactly as a floating point number.  That's why your resulting calculations aren't coming out as even integers.

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
S(t-1/dt)
```

can be replaced by

```
S(uint32(t-1/dt))
```

And similarly for I.
Also you might want to save 1/dt hardcoded as 100000 as suggested above.
I reckon this will improve the comparison.